# drupal_write_record in drupal 6 returning false

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

When I run `drupal_write_record`, it always comes back false.  I've debugged into the function and see that `drupal_get_schema` function, found inside `drupal_write_record` function, returns false.  Further more, if I debug into `drupal_get_schema` function and look at

```
 $schema = $cached->data;
```

My new table is not included in the `$schema` array.  I've tried flushing the cache, reinstalling the module, and running update.php but nothing helps.  In the event it helps, I've also included the .install file I wrote that adds the new table to the database:

```
<?php
// $Id: my_module.install,v 1.00.0.1 2012/10/21 00:23:32  Exp $

/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema().
 */
function my_module_schema() {
      $schema = array();
      $schema['my_module_pending_inserts'] = array(
        'fields' => array(
          'id' => array(
             'description' => 'primary key',
             'type' => 'serial',
             'size' => 'tiny',
             'not null' => TRUE,
          ),
          'json_array_data' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'not null' => TRUE,
          ),
          'successfully_run' => array(                
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => 0,
          ),
          'date_created' => array(               
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => 0,
          ),
          'date_updated' => array(               
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => 0,
          )

        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
      );
    return $schema;
}

function jira_reporting_install() {
  // Create tables.
  drupal_install_schema('my_module_pending_inserts');
}

function my_module_uninstall() {
  // Remove tables.
  drupal_uninstall_schema('my_module_pending_inserts');

  // Delete variables
  variable_del('my_module_variable1');
  variable_del('my_module_variable2');
  variable_del('my_module_variable3');   

}

function my_module_update_2() {
    $up = array();
    $tbl = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial', 'not null' => TRUE
                ),
                'json_array_data' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 250,
                    'not null' => True
                ),
                'successfully_run' => array(
                       'type' => 'int'
                ),
                'date_created' => array(
                        'type' => 'int'
                ),
                'date_updated' => array(
                        'type' => 'int'
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('id'),
        );


    db_create_table(&$up, 'my_module_pending_inserts', $tbl);
    return $up;
}
```

Comment: by uninstalling do you mean disable and then uninstall? try some debug symbols in hook_install

Comment: Hello, Yes, when I uninstall I disable then uninstall.  I've did try debugging into hook_install.  $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed($module); also returns as an empty array

Answer (score 0):

never mind, it was a typo in my _schema name